# Oracle Box Guest Additions

Tags: virtualbox

I downloaded Windows 7 Home Premium in Oracle Virtual Box 4.3.2. Tried to install Guest Additions 4.3.2 after that. Received an error: `0xE0000243`. This said that drivers for 32 bit system could not be found. I found this suggested fix:

```
To get the files you need, you have to extract them from the Windows Guest
Additions installers.  To extract them do the following:

VBoxWindowsAdditions-86 /extract /E=C:\Drivers.
```

I don't know how or where to input this. Windows 7 is guest host and Windows 8.1 is host.

Comment: Open a terminal on the host and copy the command

Answer (score 0):

The guest additions are supplied to the windows guest as an optical medium, i.e. a CD.
Your posted cmd line assumes E: as the drive letter for the optical drive.

What you supposedly have to do: tell VBox to install the Guest Additions, which will then bind the Additions to the guest as a CD containing a File called `VBoxWindowsAdditions-86.exe`.

So open a cmd window, navigate to the disc drive with `cd /D <your drive letter>`, and then call `VBoxWindowsAdditions-86.exe /extract /E=C:\Drivers`, where `C:\Drivers` is the directory where the exracted files are to be stored.